# Path issues in File upload ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am trying to implement a simple file upload, but having some troubles. When I hard-code the path it works fine. But for some reason, when I try to use a file upload, the controller name is being appended to the path

Hard coded path (what I'm trying to get):

```
@"C:\Users\Scott\Documents\The Business\MasterSpinSite\MasterSpin\MasterSpin\LOADME.txt"
```

Path I am getting an exception with (notice the "appz" controller name):

```
C:\Users\Scott\Documents\The Business\MasterSpinSite\MasterSpin\MasterSpin\appz\LOADME.txt'
```

My Controller

```
public ActionResult Load(spinnerValidation theData, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            string filePath = Request.MapPath(file.FileName);

            string input = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            string[] lines = Regex.Split(input, "#!#");
           // ...... do stuff

        }
```

My View

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

<input type="submit" value="LOAD ME!">

 </form>
```

What could be causing this behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public ActionResult Load(spinnerValidation theData, HttpPostedFileBase file)

    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            var input = sr.ReadToEnd();
            var lines = Regex.Split(input, "#!#");
        }
    }
}
```

**(bug)** `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)` return the name of file

**Edit**

change `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)` for `Server.MapPath(file.FileName)`

```
public ActionResult Load(spinnerValidation theData, HttpPostedFileBase file)

    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var filePath = Server.MapPath(file.FileName);
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            var input = sr.ReadToEnd();
            var lines = Regex.Split(input, "#!#");
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit II**

or copy to diferent path:

```
public ActionResult Load(spinnerValidation theData, HttpPostedFileBase file)

    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var fileUpload = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(fileUpload);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileUpload)) 
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileUpload))
            {
                var input = sr.ReadToEnd();
                var lines = Regex.Split(input, "#!#");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tried that and its giving a totally different path now - "Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\LOADME1.txt'."

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself the effort of the streams:

```
string filename = Request.Files["file"].FileName;
string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/YourUploadDirectory"), filename);

HttpPostedFileBase postedFile = Request.Files["file"] as HttpPostedFileBase;
postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

string input = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```